# Creating and Passing IConfiguration from a framework application

Tags: .net-core, app-config

From my .Net Framework 4.7.2 application, I am consuming a library that needs configuration as an IConfiguration object. I know the schema of the configuration and I have included the xml element in my App.config. But now I have problems with parsing this section of app.config and converting it to IConfiguration.
If I put the xml element in a separate xml file, I know that I could do something like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddXmlFile("config.xml").Build();
```

This would give me an instance of IConfiguration, but we do not want to have separate config files. Ideally to work with a single App.config.

What are my options please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get specific section of xml, and pass it instead of `IConfiguration` since `IConfigurationSection` inherits from `IConfiguration`

XML sample and code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <mySettings>
    <setting1>test</setting1>
    <setting2>abc</setting2>
  </mySettings>
</configuration>
```

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddXmlFile("test.xml").Build();

            var section = config.GetSection("mySettings");

            MethodForIConfiguration(section); // iconfiguration parameter accepts iconfigurationsection item

            var settingValue = section.GetValue<string>("setting1"); // equals "test"
        }

        private static void MethodForIConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Update.** I get your issue now, you can't use App.config since it is invalid for `.FromXmlFile` method. You could go around and pass only required part of App.config: read it, select nodes you need, save and pass to configuration builder as a stream

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = XDocument.Load("App.config");
            var node = document.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "mySettings").FirstOrDefault();

            var newDocument = new XDocument();
            newDocument.Add(node);

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            newDocument.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddXmlStream(ms).Build();

            var settingValue = config.GetValue<string>("setting1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this already, as I mentioned I do not want to have a separate test.xml file, I would like to include this section in App.config.

Comment: Thank you, Do you think doing this line (var document = XDocument.Load("App.config");) from within an application which already knows about its app.config is a clean way?

Comment: I'd not say it is clean, but I am not sure if other options (I see also building xml/json with ConfigurationManager) are any cleaner. Any workaround might look unclean because it would exist by design otherwise

Comment: Thanks, Yes, Ideally it would be nice if there was a way to use the natural framework's ConfigurationManager and it could convert that configSection to IConfiguration: <configSections>    
    <section name="mySection" type="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" />
  </configSections>

Comment: Or even convert that configSection to a custom object type and then use the ConfigurationBuilder to convert the object to IConfiguration

Comment: I think you could implement IConfiguration interface with your own implementation that would read ConfigurationManager, but it is quite a lot of work